# wp-admin not working: server says my realm

Tags: wordpress, authentication

Installed a fresh Wordpress Website. on clicking `http ://mysite.com/wp-admin` instead of showing wordpress login page, it shows auth entication required:-

[image]

Why may this be?

edit:- my .htaccess file. I don't think it password protects my wp-admin.

```
rewriteengine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*wp\-login\.php.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*admin_authenticated\=yes.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*auth.php.*$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ /auth.php?red=%1 [R,L]
rewriterule ^.*auth.php.*$ - [PT]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove all this

```
rewriteengine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*wp\-login\.php.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*admin_authenticated\=yes.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*auth.php.*$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ /auth.php?red=%1 [R,L]
rewriterule ^.*auth.php.*$ - [PT]
```

admin_authenticated is requiring a password! And I assume you haven't set up a password yet, or you tried the one you set it up as with username and password, and it didn't work.

So remove all that.

Comment: Where can I find the htaccess folder?

Comment: @Theo it's usually under `public_html` , as `.htaccess` , however you have to make sure you are not hiding any files. Some programs will auto hide sensitive files like htaccess, so you just have to find where you can make them visible. If all else fails, just contact your web host.